# Как сделать так, чтобы в PhpStorm плагин Emmet срабатывал при нажатии Enter, как это сделано в VS Code?

Tags: php, html, css, frontend, phpstorm

Допустим, в VS Code я ввожу div и нажимаю Enter, это сразу преобразовывается в такой вид: div /div.
Или ввожу ul>li*5 и нажимаю Enter, и плагин Emmet также отрабатывает.
**А как сделать так, чтобы в PhpStorm плагин Emmet работал по принципу Vs Code, а не при нажатии комбинации CTRL+ALT+] ?**

Comment: А что делает эта комбинация ? Emmet в PhpStorm отрабатывает по нажатию TAB

Comment: `CTRL+ALT+] ` - **Surround with live template**. Этот шорткат - аналог Emmet [wrap with abbreviation](https://docs.emmet.io/actions/wrap-with-abbreviation/#wrap-with-abbreviation), работает для выделенного блока. Обычный **Expand Emmet abbreviation** происходит по нажатию табуляции, шорткат можно настроить в **Settings | Editor | Emmet**, **Expand abbreviation with:**

Comment: @lena спасибо, помогло!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаю как в windows, но на маке так: `Настройки - Editor - Emmet` и там выбрать в выпадающем меню `Expand abbreviation with: Enter`

Думаю на windows в том же месте настройка.